# Integrate data from 2 different db

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

How is the MySQL query for my case :

What I want to do is I had join two table `table1_db1` and `table2_db1`. I would like to insert data from DB1 to DB2. How is the SQL Query for that?

I have 2 database.

Database 1 : DB1

Table name : table1_db1

Column name : name

Table name : table2_db1

Column name : reference

Database 2 : DB2

Table name : table1_db2

Column name : model

Column name : description

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.table1_db2 (model, description)
SELECT table1_db1.name AS model, table1_db2.reference AS description
FROM DB1.table1_db1
JOIN DB1.table1_db2 ON table1_db1.name = table1_db2.reference
;
```

Comment: can you refer to my latest edit? in db2 there are two column